# return type of decltype(*this)

Tags: c++11, decltype

I think I might have missed the subtlety in move construction because when I change the line `Foo copy(*this);` to `decltype(*this) copy(*this);`, I am thoroughly surprised by the output.

I checked it against, clang++-3.5 and g++-4.9, with the same behavior.

Would really appreciate a quick tip from the C++11 guru.

Update:  Just forced the compiler to print the type of `decltype(*this)`, it is actually a reference type i.e. `Foo&`.

```
class Foo {
    public: 
        Foo(int a): val(a) {}

        operator int() { return val; }

        auto& operator++() {
            val++;
            return *this;
        }

        auto operator++(int) {
            //Foo copy(*this);
            decltype(*this) copy(*this);
            ++(*this);
            return copy;
        }
    private:
        int val;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo=1;
    cout << "foo++ = " << foo++ << "\n";
    cout << "foo++ = " << foo++ << "\n";
    cout << "foo = " << foo << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output

```
foo++ = 2
foo++ = 3
foo = 3
```

Comment: `decltype(*this)` is `Foo&`.

Comment: what does that have to do with move construction though? `decltype` doesn't have anything to do with move construction and is completely independent of it.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl it's not about the move constructor. It's just that when ``copy`` is a reference, it's an alias for the original object. So a copy of the original object gets returned. When copy is a value type, the object is copied, and what's returned is the copy, before ++ was applied. What I don't understand is why ``decltype(*this)`` is ``Foo&``.

Comment: I still don't understand the exact problem that's confusing you but well, hope my answer helps a bit at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion as to why `decltyp(*this)` is `Foo&` and not `Foo` in your case. Firstly, think about dereferencing a pointer always resulting in a reference to the pointed to object.

```
temp = *ptr // this would work if dereferencing returned by value or by reference
*ptr = expr // this would only work if dereferencing results in a reference.
```

Now `decltype(expr)` always gives you exactly the same type as the expr. For you `*this` is of type `Foo&`.

If you want type deduction without it resulting in a reference use `auto` instead of `decltype`, so:

```
auto copy(*this);
```

instead of

```
decltype(*this) copy(*this);
```

Also I don't know why your question is talking about move construction so much as there is no move involved anywhere.

Comment: It only took me a moment more to figure that decltype(*this) is really a reference type.  Thanks for writing up an answer.